# Run WCF Web Service automatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio, web-services

I've created a WCF Web Service and I want to change the 'baseAddress' value in the App.config dynamically without been called from another program.

My problem is :

When my IP address changes, I cannot access  to this WCF remotely

Comment: The key would be to access it via a routed domain name, meaning you just need to update your DNS settings for that domain - messing around with the service in this manner (given the information we have) seems unreasonable. And of course, once the IP changes, improbable.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment how ? because the WCF is stored in laptop who don't even have an IIS. I'm just using Windows Services.

Comment: The laptop you're calling from? Then how is that 'remote'? Which version of Windows are you using? Any modern version will have IIS by default.

Comment: I created a Console App that embed a WCF using Windows Service using this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx so no need to have IIS and it's working on Windows XP/7

Answer (score 1):

Does this match with wath you want to do?
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/06/03/dynamically-updating-wcf-endpoint-addresses-in-wsdl-meta-data/

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the [discovery mechanism of WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx) if the clients are in the same network.